# channels how to know the name of the group an event is sent inside?

Tags: django, django-channels

So I have a websockets consumer like this

```py
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class GatewayEventsConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    """
    An ASGI consumer for gateway event sending. Any authenticated
    user can connect to this consumer. Users receive personalized events
    based on the permissions they have.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def connect(self):
        user = self.scope['user']
        if user.is_anonymous:
            # close the connection if the
            # user isn't authenticated yet
            await self.close()

        for member in user.member_set.all():
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(member.box.id, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        for member in self.scope['user'].member_set.all():
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(member.box.id, self.channel_name)

    async def fire_event(self, event: dict):
        # need to implement caching
        formatted = {
            'data': event['data'],
            'event': event['event'],
        }
        required_permissions = event.get('listener_permissions', [])
        overwrite_channel = event.get('overwrite_channel', None)
        # need to know which group the event is being sent inside
        # to get the box-id, and thus get the member to check perms
        member_permissions = []
        if not required_permissions or required_permissions in member_permissions:
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(formatted))
```

on websocket connect, I put the user into groups according to the boxes they are a part of. On disconnect, I remove them all. Now, this is how I fire my events.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=api_models.Upload)
def on_upload_save(instance=None, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.pop('created', False):
        return async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            instance.box.id,
            {
                'type': 'fire_event',
                'event': 'UPLOAD_CREATE',
                'listener_permissions': ['READ_UPLOADS'],
                'overwrite_channel': instance.channel,
                'data': api_serializers.PartialUploadSerializer(instance).data
            }
        )
```

So the event is being sent to a group with the box-id here.
However, I also need to check box-specific permissions for these events.
So inside the `fire_event` method, I need to do this.

```py
    async def fire_event(self, event: dict):
        # need to implement caching
        formatted = {
            'data': event['data'],
            'event': event['event'],
        }
        required_permissions = event.get('listener_permissions', [])
        overwrite_channel = event.get('overwrite_channel', None)
        # need to know which group the event is being sent inside
        # to get the box-id, and thus get the member to check perms
        member_permissions = []
        if not required_permissions or required_permissions in member_permissions:
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(formatted))
```

I need to know in which group this event is being sent under to determine permissions for the user. Is there any way to achieve this?